# can not install vuejs using npm on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, npm

[image]

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/sabbir/package-lock.json'
```

I am new on ubuntu
I can not install vue js on my ubuntu 20.4
I am having this error.Having this same error installing some other application.Why is this happening?
help me out
thanks

Comment: You may not have write permission on your home directory (which is unlikely) or there may already be a file called `package-lock.json` in your home directory which is read-only. Please run `ls -l ~/package-lock.json` and add the output to your question.

Comment: sabbir@sabbir-X510UQ:~$ ls -l ~/package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42249 এপ্রিল    25 23:39 /home/sabbir/package-lock.json     this is the output i got

Answer (score 0):

You already have a file `package-lock.json` in your home directory, which is owned by `root`. You can't remove or replace that file without special permissions. Two thoughts:

1. To find which files in your home directory are owned by `root`, do `ls -la ~ | grep root`. To take back ownership of `package-lock.json`, do `sudo chown myuser:myuser package-lock.json`. Replace `myuser` with your actual user name. Do the same for any other files that ought to be owned by you.
2. It is not advisable to build web applications directly in your home directory. If you want to build more than one, where should the next one go? Create a folder "webapplications" and within that one, create another folder "my first webapplication" (or whatever) and build your web app there.